# Subsequential limit of $S_n=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I'm having trouble identifying the subsequences, or patterns of the sequence.

I recognize the problem can be rewritten:

$S_n=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^n=-\frac{\sqrt{2}^n}{4^n}$

And if I had to take a guess at what I thought were my subsequences I'd say:

$-\sqrt{2}^n$ and $-\frac{1}{4^n}$

Using that I'd say the limit  sup is 0 and limit inf is $-\infty$

Comment: You're re-writing is wrong. It should be: $$S_n=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}\right)^n=(-1)^n\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\right)^n=(-1)^n\frac{(\sqrt{2})^n}{4^n}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write it as:$$S_{ n }=\left( -\frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 4 }  \right) ^{ n }=\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{ n } }{ \left(2\sqrt { 2 }\right)^n  } $$ then give for n odd and even numbers in order to find subsequences

Comment: I see that both subsequences converge to $0$.  So limit sup = lim inf = 0?

Comment: @free_mind,you are right

Answer (score 1):

Try to show that

$$|x|<1\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} x^n=0$$